# Creating model effect to new view using Storyboard with a UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I'm updating an app with more options when they click the `add` button. Before, when they clicked it, a certain screen came up with a model transition. This I could easily do from the .storyboard file, but since the UIActionSheet does not show up in the .storyboard file, I have no way to link it to the other scene. How do I do this?

This is the code I have right now:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 1:
            //  where somehow I need to get to the next scene using storyboard
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This may not matter, but I'm using a UITableView within a TabBar when the action sheet is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

You might want to make sure the action sheet is being dismissed first.

Comment: Is `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` called from `self` Also, what is the `sender` set too?

Comment: If `self` is a view controller that came from the storyboard, then the storyboard is `self.storyboard`. So you can call it on `self.storyboard`.

Comment: Make sure you spell the identifier correctly. Capitalization matters! The `sender` is up to you; it is not important unless you are checking for it in a later method such as `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

Comment: This is all in the documentation, you know.